# how to login to a HTTPS site and then post data to protected page using php curl

Tags: php, http, redirect, curl, cookies

I am trying to access a website's protected web page where I need to post some JSON data to a page, but it always shows status code 200 and redirects me to a page which says
"Please enable browser cookie" and then shows me the login page as a response, both of the curl executions return 200 status code. I also give the cookie.txt correct permission i.e, 644. **BUT I FOUND THAT COOKIE.TXT is not modifying**
any help would be appreciated.

php curl code:

```
<?php 

//username and password of account
$username = trim($_POST["email"]);
$password = trim($_POST["password"]);
echo "username=$username pass:$password";
$loginUrl = 'https://www.pogrande.com/login.php?action=process';
//The username or email address of the account.
define('USERNAME', $username);

//The password of the account.
define('PASSWORD', $password);

//Set a user agent. This basically tells the server that we are using Chrome ;)
define('USER_AGENT', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.2309.372 Safari/537.36');

//Where our cookie information will be stored (needed for authentication).
define('COOKIE_FILE', 'cookie.txt');

//URL of the login form.
define('LOGIN_FORM_URL', 'https://www.pogrande.com/login.php');

//Login action URL. Sometimes, this is the same URL as the login form.
define('LOGIN_ACTION_URL', 'https://www.pogrande.com/login.php?action=process');


//An associative array that represents the required form fields.
//You will need to change the keys / index names to match the name of the form
//fields.
$postValues = array(
    'email_address' => USERNAME,
    'password' => PASSWORD
);

//Initiate cURL.
$curl = curl_init();

//Set the URL that we want to send our POST request to. In this
//case, it's the action URL of the login form.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, LOGIN_ACTION_URL);

//Tell cURL that we want to carry out a POST request.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

//Set our post fields / date (from the array above).
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postValues));

//We don't want any HTTPS errors.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

//Where our cookie details are saved. This is typically required
//for authentication, as the session ID is usually saved in the cookie file.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);

//Sets the user agent. Some websites will attempt to block bot user agents.
//Hence the reason I gave it a Chrome user agent.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

//Tells cURL to return the output once the request has been executed.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Allows us to set the referer header. In this particular case, we are 
//fooling the server into thinking that we were referred by the login form.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, LOGIN_FORM_URL);

//Do we want to follow any redirects?
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

//Execute the login request.
curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo "status=$status"; 
//Check for errors!
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));
}

$url = $_POST['url'];   
$content = $outp;//json_encode("your data to be sent");

//We should be logged in by now. Let's attempt to access a password protected page
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//Use the same cookie file.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE);

//Use the same user agent, just in case it is used by the server for session validation.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, USER_AGENT);

//We don't want any HTTPS / SSL errors.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

//Execute the GET request and print out the result.
curl_exec($curl);//the login is now done and you can continue to get the
//protected content.

/*
$url = $_POST['url'];    
$content = $outp;//json_encode("your data to be sent");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
*/
$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 201 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}


curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
//alert($response);*/
}
}

?>
```

Comment: is your browser cookies is disabled?

Comment: No URL working fine with browser, I am asking about PHP CURL

Comment: @PrafulSharma add `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` to second curl block.  Let second call follow redirect and receive any cookie from redirected pages.  Your codes looks ok, just need to add this to second block.

Comment: @LasVegasCoder just modified the code according to you but still giving same error.
Error: call to URL https://www.pXXXXe.com/edi.php failed with status 200, response --> code of login page.

Comment: @PrafulSharma the only way to pinpoint this error is by dumping result from  the two `curl_exec( $ch )`, and examine the return data.  I hate to guess, it's programmer's habit to guess.  Let's dig right into it.

Comment: @LasVegasCoder i just checked after var_dump() the result but it now shows me two login pages in the result. it looks like the result variable contains the whole login page code.

Comment: @PrafulSharma that's a good sign, now you can go through the code to find out what you were missing.

Comment: @LasVegasCoder I am unable to find what is wrong. the login page is  https://www.pogrande.com/login.php

Comment: @PrafulSharma this should be easy, first thing when login using curl or related method, you will need to dump your httpHeaders first into a txt file by login in normally without script.  Now that you have dumped data in txt, you can use curl to imitate how normal login works.  I cannot do the dumping for you, It's getting late here :(

Comment: The login page you mentioned redirects me to `https://www.pogrande.com/cookie_usage.php` in my browser, even though cookies are accepted ... sounds like that site itself might not be working properly in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe Is there any issue of linux based systems? as i am using chrome over windows on that the link is working fine. But my online server is of linux.

Comment: I am using Chrome on Windows, and get redirected on the first try to access the login URL. When I try to access it again afterwards, the cookies are already there, and it works. This site is just doing a bad job at detecting this properly ...

Comment: is there any possible fix in the code so that it can bypass the error. @CBroe any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well you could try and request the login URL twice ... if that works inside the browser, then it might work with cURL, too.

Comment: @CBroe Great it works. Thanks a lot.